# Convert yii1 query to yii2

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii1. I would like to convert this below query to yii2. May I know the difference between condition and param in yii2?

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'amount, name, level';
$criteria->condition = "account_type = :account_type";
$criteria->params=(array(':account_type'=>'credit'));
$result = $this->model()->find($criteria);
```

I have tried the below sample. But it's not giving me the same return as yii1 query.

```
$result = Model::find()
           ->select(['amount, name, level'])
           ->where(['account_type' => $account_type, 'account_type' => 'credit'])
           ->one();
```

Comment: what is in `$account_type` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = Model::find()
       ->select(['amount, name, level'])
       ->where(['account_type' => 'credit'])
       ->one();
```